# Iterate Through Rows of DB2 Data into an Array using PSObject

Tags: windows, powershell, db2

I'm able to pull a record count with this code below.  But unable to loop through the rows and extract into an array.

I have it working in SQL Server using SQL DataAdaptor - now I need to use the IBM.Data.DB2.

```
$factory = [System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories]::GetFactory('IBM.Data.DB2')
$cstrbld = $factory.CreateConnectionStringBuilder()
$cstrbld.Database = 'dbname'
$cstrbld.UserID = 'username'
$cstrbld.Password = 'password'
$cstrbld.Server = 'servername:50001'
$dbconn = $factory.CreateConnection()
$dbconn.ConnectionString = $cstrbld.ConnectionString
$dbconn.Open()
###############
########################################################################################################################################
####   THE QUERY STATEMENT  
########################################################################################################################################
$dbcmd = $dbconn.CreateCommand()
########################################################################################################################################
$dbcmd.CommandText = 'SELECT PFIWORKUNIT,ACTOR,FLOWDEFINITION,WORKTITLE,STATUS FROM LAWSON.PFIWORKUNIT WHERE STATUS BETWEEN 0 AND 9'
########################################################################################################################################
# load it right into a DataTable
$dt = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
$dt.Load($dbcmd.ExecuteReader())
$dt.data
write-host $dt.Rows[0].ItemArray[0] ### <-getting the record count


########################################################################################################################################
## But Below I can reference the rows individually
########################################################################################################################################

$exportObject=@() 
     ForEach ($dt.Rows[0].ItemArray[0]) {
      
        $ExciterObject = New-Object PSObject
        $ExciterObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "PFIWORKUNIT" -Value $row.PFIWORKUNIT
        $ExciterObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "ACTOR" -Value $row.ACTOR 
        $ExciterObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "FLOWDEFINITION" -Value $row.FLOWDEFINITION 
        $ExciterObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "WORKTITLE" -Value $row.WORKTITLE 
        $ExciterObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "STATUS" -Value $row.STATUS
        $exportObject += $ExciterObject
        }


##I'm able to do this in Windows SQL Server using the Fill - but here it allows me only the Load method with IBM DB2.

$DataAdapter = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter $SqlCommand
$dataset = new-object System.Data.Dataset
$rowCount = $DataAdapter.Fill($dataset)
```

Comment: I'm not a DB2 expert, but I can't help but feel like the issue is your query. Shouldn't it be something like `$dbcmd.CommandText = 'SELECT * FROM "statement works"'`, assuming your table name is "statement works"?

Comment: this statement is confirmed working -- $dbcmd.CommandText = 'SELECT PFIWORKUNIT,ACTOR,FLOWDEFINITION,WORKTITLE,STATUS FROM LAWSON.PFIWORKUNIT WHERE STATUS BETWEEN 0 AND 9'

Comment: This works with SQL but not DB2 --  ForEach ($row in $dataset.Tables[0].Rows)  -- For some reason I can't use Tables(0)

Comment: You realize you're using different objects for SQL and DB2 right? DB2 you create a System.Data.Data**Table** and SQL you create a System.Data.Data**Set**. That may be why it works for SQL and not DB2. Looking at the [script](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/SQLvariant/e9bede8a6bf4e65408da1f0a7f7faffc/raw/65a3f934e3d14223173d56edcb2d079d8ec58441/Invoke-DB2Query.ps1) that I found on [this blog](https://sqlvariant.com/2021/02/query-db2-from-powershell/) it looks like you want a DataSet not a DataTable.

Comment: Yes - Datatable is working - I'm having no luck with populating the PSObjects from each row via ForEach --
 # load it right into a DataTable
 $dt = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
 $dt.Load($dbcmd.ExecuteReader())
 $dt.data
 write-host $dt.Rows[0].ItemArray[0] ### <-getting the record count
8062